# Different includePaths for different folders in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, c, linux, visual-studio-code

I'm working on an embedded linux project. In this project, when i code, i usually go back and forth between a c++ user space application and a linux driver used by the user space application.

I use VSCode and in my C/C++ properties, to allow intellisense to be helpful when working on the linux driver, i needed add to the `"includePath"` the path to the linux include directory (`"${workspaceFolder}/.../linux/include"`).

This is working fine from the linux driver point of view, the only problem is that this include path is used by intellisense also when i work on the user space application and obviously a few names and macros end up in conflict here and there (e.g. `std::min` and `std::max` conflict with the `min` and `max` macros from the linux include files).

So my question is: is it possible to specify an include path only for a subfolder of my project and not for the whole project? I would like intellisense to consider the `linux/include` folder as `includePath` but only for a specific subfolder of my project (the linux driver one). If it's possible, how can this be achieved?

I know i could consider the userspace application and the driver as two different and separate projects, each with its own cpp properties, but that would make switching between the two subprojects a bit more cumbersome.

Comment: Can you not use the 2 include paths for the entire project?

Comment: This is how it's setup right now. the problem is that as soon as i use `std::min` or `std::max` in the userspace code intellisense mistakenly thinks it's the `min` or `max` macro from the kernel include files and after that line everything becomes a red squiggly line. It's usable and i can live with it, it's just a bit annoying.

Comment: One solution, though it might be undesirable, is to change the name of the `min` and `max` kernel macros. I think vscode has a built-in function for changing the name of a variable, called `Rename Symbol`, but I am not sure about macros.